# Filtration of sum of independent sub-martingales

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, martingales

Let $x_1,\ldots, x_n$ be independent continuous martingales with filtrations $\mathcal{F}^1_{t},\ldots, \mathcal{F}^n_{t}$. Let $Y_i=(x_i)^2$ be the associated sub-martingale with each $x_i$ (we can derive this from the fact that $x^2$ is a convex function, and apply Jensen’s inequality).

Given the independence of the $x_i$’s, $S=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$ is also a sub-martingale. What is the filtration it is a sub-martingale with respect to?

Further, suppose $x_i$’s are a martingale with respect to some common filtration $\mathcal{G}$, which is the filtration associated with some predictable process. Each $x_i$ can be thought of as the process viewed on some subset of its support. Can we drop the independence assumption then, and say $S$ is a sub-martingale wrt filtration $\mathcal{G}$?

I think that my question is related to [Martingale preservation under independent enlargement of filtration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/273015/martingale-preservation-under-independent-enlargement-of-filtration), but could use some help with an intermediate explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ are independent they are also martingales wrt. the filtration $\mathcal{F}=(\mathcal{F}_t)$ where $\mathcal{F}_t=\sigma(\mathcal{F}^1_t,\dotsc,\mathcal{F}^n_t)$. Hence, $Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n$ are sub-martingales wrt. $\mathcal{F}$ and so is the sum $S$.

In the above, if $x_1,\dotsc,x_n$ are no longer assumed to be independent independent then they are no longer guaranteed to be $\mathcal{F}$-martingales. However, since you assume that they are instead $\mathcal{G}$-martingales it follows that $Y_1,\dotsc,Y_n$ are $\mathcal{G}$-sub-martingales and ultimately that $S$ is a $\mathcal{G}$-sub-martingale. Note that independence is not needed for a sum of sub-martingales (wrt. the same filtration) to be a sub-martingale.

Comment: Thank you. So if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are all martingales wrt filtration $\mathcal{G}$, then $S$ is a submartingale wrt to filtration $\mathcal{G}$. But if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are also martingales wrt to filtrations $\mathcal{F}_t^1,\ldots,\mathcal{F}_t^n$, does this mean that $\mathcal{F}_t\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ or even stronger, if $\mathcal{F}_t$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are of minimal size, are they equal?

Comment: Sorry and a second question: what if predictable process $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable, but contains a lot of unnecessary information for $x_i$ (perhaps $x_i$ could just be based on some small subset of the support of $X$). Say filtration $\mathcal{F}_t^i$ is sufficient for $x_i$ to be a martingale, but $x_i$ is also $\mathcal{G}$ adapted. Then is $x_i$ with respect to $\mathcal{G}$ also a martingale (even though $\mathcal{G}$ has lots of unnecessary information)? Is $\mathcal{F}_t^i\subset\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: First question: Here you cannot say much. $x_1$ will be adapted to both $\mathcal{F}^1$ and $\mathcal{G}$. However, if $\mathcal{F}^11$ is the natural filtration generated by $x_1$ (i.e. $\mathcal{F}^1_t=\sigma(x_1(s)\mid s\leq t)$ then we have $\mathcal{F}^1\subseteq\mathcal{G}$.

Comment: Second question: If $\mathcal{F}^1_t\subseteq\mathcal{G}_t$ for all $t$, $x_1$ is a martingale wrt. $\mathcal{F}^1$, and $x_1$ is $\mathcal{G}$-adapted you can generally not conclude that $x_1$ is also a martingale wrt. $\mathcal{G}$. However, if $x_1$ is $\mathcal{F}^1$-adapted and a martingale wrt. $\mathcal{G}$, then it is also a martingale wrt. $\mathcal{F}^1$. This is a simple application of the tower property.